# Save dutch date

Tags: django

I have an input field with the following value: 12-04-2012

This is a Dutch date that I want to save in the database. Database Field is Date.

How can I save a non English date into the database?

I tried:

HTML

```
<input id="id_delivery_date" type="text" value="12-04-2012" name="delivery_date">
```

DJANGO

```
def save(self, user, session):
    self.order.delivery_date = self.cleaned_data['delivery_date']
    self.order.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [datetime.strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse the string and create a datetime object that can directly be assigned to the database field.

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('12-04-2012', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Another option would be to use string processing, but this is quite a hack and not recommended.

```
>>> '-'.join(reversed('12-04-2012'.split('-')))
'2012-04-12'
```

Answer (score 0):

By Dutch date, I assume you mean the format is MM-DD-YYYY. You can parse this into a `datetime` object with

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime("12-04-2012", "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Comment: @NelsonVarela: oops, thinko on my part.